# How to protect first call in useQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, graphql

```
const [lastViewId, setLastViewId] = useState<string>("");

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(
  GET_USER, 
  variables: { id: user_id }
);

const lastViewData = useQuery(
  GET_LAST_VIEW_DATA, 
  variables: { id: lastViewId }
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (loading || !data) return;

  if (data && data.user && data.user.lastViewId) {
    setLastViewId(data.user.lastViewId)
  }
}, [loading]);
```

As you can see, `GET_LAST_VIEW_DATA` is called with no `lastViewId` before `lastViewId` is set.

But I'd like to `GET_LAST_VIEW_DATA` is called after lastViewId is set.

How can I protect the first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useLazyQuery` is the best solution for this issue.

```
import {useLazyQuery} from '@apollo/react-hooks';
...
const [getLastViewData, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
  GET_LAST_VIEW_DATA,
  { variables: { id: lastViewId } }
);
...
```

You can call `getLastViewData` whenever you want.